# Calculate time span between two specific statuses on the database for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on the database that contains statuses updated on each vehicle I have, I want to calculate how many days each vehicle spends time between two specific statuses 'Maintenance' and 'Read'.

My table looks something like this

[image]

and I want to result to be like this, only show the number of days a vehicle spends in maintenance before becoming ready on a specific day

[image]

The code I written looks like this

```
drop table if exists #temps1

select

 VehicleId,

 json_value(VehiclesHistoryStatusID.text,'$.en') as VehiclesHistoryStatus,

VehiclesHistory.CreationTime,

datediff(day, VehiclesHistory.CreationTime , 
lead(VehiclesHistory.CreationTime ) over (order by VehiclesHistory.CreationTime ) ) as days,

lag(json_value(VehiclesHistoryStatusID.text,'$.en')) over (order by VehiclesHistory.CreationTime) as PrevStatus,

case 

when   (lag(json_value(VehiclesHistoryStatusID.text,'$.en')) over (order by VehiclesHistory.CreationTime) <> json_value(VehiclesHistoryStatusID.text,'$.en')) THEN datediff(day, VehiclesHistory.CreationTime , (lag(VehiclesHistory.CreationTime ) over (order by VehiclesHistory.CreationTime ))) else 0 end as testing


into #temps1

from fleet.VehicleHistory VehiclesHistory
left join Fleet.Lookups as VehiclesHistoryStatusID on VehiclesHistoryStatusID.Id = VehiclesHistory.StatusId


where (year(VehiclesHistory.CreationTime) > 2021 and (VehiclesHistory.StatusId = 140 Or VehiclesHistory.StatusId = 144) )

group by VehiclesHistory.VehicleId ,VehiclesHistory.CreationTime , VehiclesHistoryStatusID.text 

order by  VehicleId desc

drop table if exists #temps2

select * into #temps2  from #temps1 where testing <> 0

select * from #temps2
```

Comment: "I want" is not a question. Stack Overflow isn't a free contract coding service. What T-SQL have you written to return your expected results? Why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: VehichleID 2 is not Ready according to the table. Whey it has 1 in the last column of the second table?

Comment: the code i have written works when i only specify a vehicleId in the where clause but when i remove it the code breaks!

Comment: What code? There's no code here. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74674003/edit) your question to include the problematic code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning code attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT innerQ.VehichleID,innerQ.CreationDate,innerQ.Status
,SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,innerQ.PrevMaintenance,innerQ.CreationDate)) AS DayDuration

FROM
(
SELECT t1.VehichleID,t1.CreationDate,t1.Status,
(SELECT top(1) t2.CreationDate FROM dbo.Test t2 
    WHERE t1.VehichleID=t2.VehichleID
    AND t2.CreationDate<t1.CreationDate
    AND t2.Status='Maintenance'
    ORDER BY t2.CreationDate Desc) AS PrevMaintenance
FROM
dbo.Test t1 WHERE t1.Status='Ready'
) innerQ
WHERE innerQ.PrevMaintenance IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY innerQ.VehichleID,innerQ.CreationDate,innerQ.Status
```

In this query first we are finding the most recent 'maintenance' date before each 'ready' date in the inner most query (if exists). Then calculate the time span with `DATEDIFF` and sum all this spans for each vehicle.

Comment: a very good answer thank you, only one tweak needed.

Comment: your code calculates the date difference between the maintenance status and every ready status after it. can the code be modified to only calculate the first ready status after each maintenance status? @MD Zand

Comment: simply remove the sum and group by

Comment: removed them still same result?

Comment: Remove the `sum` before DATEDIFF and then remove the `Group By` full line.  The code then will show the maintenance length of each ready state which is after a maintenance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250136/discussion-between-abood-jayyousi-and-md-zand).